# Is There a New Way of Starting Plasmashell in 19.04?

Tags: kubuntu, suspend, kde, 19.04

Every time I close my laptop lid for some amount of time, the graphics for files mess up and display inacurate filenames  and have graphical issues upon resume.

Usually I remove this by executing `killall plasmashell && kstart plasmashell`, but I noticed that this doesn't appear to work in the new Disco Dingo release.

I got an error message indicating that kstart wasn't available as a command and that I should install `kde-runtime` if I wanted to use it?

Has some other method of starting plasmashell been added? How can I restart plasmashell?

Comment: I haven't upgraded to 19.04 yet, but this sounds alarming, that the old trick no longer works. As a shot in the dark, do you do this in Krunner or a terminal (whether pre-opened, via shortcut, or always-open Yakuake)?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on Kubuntu 19.04.
Try using the following instead to restart your plasmashell:

```
killall plasmashell && kstart5 plasmashell
```

Comment: Another option, from [here](https://www.lifewire.com/kubuntu-p2-2202573): `kquitapp5 plasmashell && kstart5 plasmashell`.